Which Lorentzian metrics are comformally equivalent to some Einstein metric or some Ricci flat metric?
I know that given a conformally flat Lorentzian metric, I can implement a Weyl transformation,
$$g_\text{ab}\mapsto\bar{g}_\text{ab}=\Omega^2 g_\text{ab}$$
to flatten it as $\bar{g}_\text{ab}=\eta_\text{ab}$. In fact, by taking the determinant we can find that $\Omega^8=\vert\bar{g}\vert/\vert g\vert$ given that we are working in $n=4$ dimensions. Since $\bar{g}_\text{ab}=\eta_\text{ab}$ is flat we know that there is some coordinate system for which we have $\vert\bar{g} \vert=\vert\eta \vert=1$ globally. Hence, in this coordinate system, we have that $\Omega=\vert g\vert^{-1/8}$ flattens the metric. Namely, $\bar{g}_\text{ab}=\vert g\vert^{-1/4}g_\text{ab}$ will be flat. In particular it will be Ricci-flat $\bar{R}_\text{ab}=0$ as well as Einstein $\bar{G}_\text{ab}=0$.
My question is, does the fact that we end up with $\bar{R}_\text{ab}=0$ and/or $\bar{G}_\text{ab}=0$ depend upon the fact that we already had $C^\text{a}{}_\text{bcd}=0$ before the Weyl transformation? That is, suppose that I had instead started from a generic Lorentzian metric $g_\text{ab}$ which is not conformally flat, $C^\text{a}{}_\text{bcd}\not=0$. Is there some Weyl transformation I can perform (something like $\Omega=\vert g\vert^{-1/8}$) such that I end up with $\bar{g}_\text{ab}$ having either of the following curvature profiles?
$$\text{Ricci flat: }\quad \bar{R}_\text{ab}=0, \quad\text{ and }\quad \bar{C}^\text{a}{}_\text{bcd}=C^\text{a}{}_\text{bcd}\not=0$$
or
$$\text{Einstein: }\quad \bar{G}_\text{ab}=0, \quad\text{ and }\quad \bar{C}^\text{a}{}_\text{bcd}=C^\text{a}{}_\text{bcd}\not=0$$
I know that these Ricci curvature and the Weyl curvature are in some sense algebraically independent from each other. So I am hopeful that this is possible.
Edit: I am growing doubtful that my hopes are met. See, for instance, slide 5 and 9 of this presentation. What is known then about the class of Lorentzian metrics which are conformally Einstein? And the class which are conformally Ricci-flat? Are these "big" or "useful" classes of spacetimes? Moreso than a mathematical characterization I would like to know whether or not the most common solutions to GR have either of these properties.
$\bullet$ Any vacuum solution to GR (e.g., Schwartzchild and Kerr) is Einstein correct? Hence it is (trivially) conformally Einstein as well, right? But what about FRW? What about Reissner–Nordström? etc. etc.
$\bullet$ Is it possible that the metric in the actual world (with all its complexity) is conformally Einstein? If I were to claim that it is, what evidence would you provide against me? Don't just say that the real world can't be conformally Einstein because some particularly useful toy-model (e.g., Reissner–Nordström) isn't. Couldn't there be some near-by good-enough conformally Einstein solution which meets the data just as well?

I mean you can have $R\neq 0$ and $C_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta }=0$, which is the case for conformally flat spacetimes like FRW (more formally Petrov type $\mathbf{O}$ spacetimes in terms of Newman-Penrose scalars). This is regardless of Weyl transformations, but if you have a conformally flat spacetime there is no exact physical relation between $R$ and $C$. This is why in making sense of gravitational entropy we choose descriptions with the Weyl invariant $C_{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta }C^{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta }$ and not $R_{\alpha \beta }R^{\alpha \beta }\dots $ invariants.

You can't set the metric to be globally flat, unless the space is truly flat. If you have non-trivial curvature locally, the best you can hope for is to make the metric flat at that point, but some of its derivatives will necessarily be non-vanishing at that same point.
